# Python Creating a new list from an existing list

Tags: python, list, computer-vision, contour

I would like to create a list of quadrilateral contours from the existing list of contours. I am rather new to coding so please bear with my attempted code I will use to demondstrate the objective.

```
#Get Contours from an Image
(contours,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(image,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Work in progress
def ListQuads(contours,c=0):
    l = len(contours)  #Gets total number of contours
    while l > c:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            Quads[c] = approx
            c = c + 1
    return Quads

Quads = ListQuads(contours)
```

Comment: so you want to make a copy of `contours`?

Comment: In your function `ListQuads` you use the variable `Quads` which is not defined before. Also if you want to iterate through a list, it is better to use the `for ... in` loop. Example: `for i in contours:` where `i` is a list item, you can use another name if you want.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Can you explain some more what you mean by create a list from an existing list?

Comment: The goal is to extract the contour with 4 edges and create a new list of only those contours.

Answer (score 2):

The way this is normally done in Python is by using comprehensions:

```
approximations = [cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
                  for c in contours]
quads = [apx for apx in approximations if len(apx) == 4]
```

you could even get this in a single statement by nesting the `aproximations` in the `quads` comprehension, but this wouldn't improve readability.

Saving on write is considered OK in Python only if reading becomes easier.

Note that you can also use a generator expression instead of a comprehension for the first expression by using regular parenthesis `(...)` instead of square brackets `[...]` around it.

In this case the meaning will be of making the computation of `approximations` "lazy", saving memory if the original list is very long.

Comment: Could make `apxs` a generator expression instead of constructing a temporary list by using parentheses around it instead of square brackets — and this wouldn't hurt readability.

Comment: @martineau: Added a note about it. Thanks.